# add a sub element in d3js using data binding

Tags: d3.js

I have a table data like

- ID, Name, Value
- 001, ABC, 123
- 002, DEF, 345

and I would like to display it like:

```
<div id="001">
<h1>ABC</h1> <p>123</p>
```

I tried the following:

```
var divs = root.selectAll("div").data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d.ID; })
            .append("h1")
            .text(function (d) { return d.Name; })
            .selectAll("div p").data(function (d) { return d; })
            .enter().append("p")
            .text(function (d) { return d.Value; })
```

However it only display the first level. I tried a few other options but was unsuccessful, either display nothing or display all values in each element.

I have the feeling I am missing something obvious, any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main changes:

- firstly, you have to break your selection, appending the `<h>` and the `<p>` elements to `divs`. So, you'll have as many divs as objects in your data array. However, for each div, you'll append one `<h>` and one `<p>` element. Right now, you're kind of appending (more on that below) the `<p>` elements to the `<h>`, not to the divs.
- Secondly, you should not create a nested selection rebinding data
  (since you don't have inner arrays here, but only objects inside an
  array). That would make sense if you had several `<p>` elements for each div, but you don't.

So, this should be your code:

```
var divs = root.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d.ID;
  });

divs.append("h1")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.Name;
  });

divs.append("p")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.Value;
  });
```

And this creates this structure:

```
<div id="001">
    <h1>ABC</h1>
    <p>123</p>
</div>
<div id="002">
    <h1>DEF</h1>
    <p>345</p>
</div>
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
  ID: "001",
  Name: "ABC",
  Value: "123"
}, {
  ID: "002",
  Name: "DEF",
  Value: "345"
}];

var root = d3.select("body");

var divs = root.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d.ID;
  });

divs.append("h1")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.Name;
  });

divs.append("p")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.Value;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```